# Enormous difference in the number of Hash Table collisions with linear probing based on input data

Tags: java, performance, hash, hashtable, distribution

I am running performance tests on a Hash Table while trying two different data sets and array sizes.

The first data set contains 100 000 random Integers converted to strings fe. "-52917" "12345678" computed like so :

```
  public static String[] prepareRandomWords() {
        Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
        int maxNumOfWords = 100_000;
        int seed = 123;
        Random rand = new Random(seed);

        while (words.size() < maxNumOfWords) {
            words.add(String.valueOf(rand.nextInt()));
        }

        return words.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

The second data set is the MIT list of 100 000 words that can be found here : [https://www.mit.edu/~ecprice/wordlist.100000](https://www.mit.edu/%7Eecprice/wordlist.100000)

This is the put function I use to insert elements into the table :

```
@Override
    public void put(T newElem) {
        validateInputElem(newElem);
        resizeIfNeeded();

        int key = newElem.hashCode(); // java's native String.hashCode()
        int i = 0;
        int hashId = hashFunc(key, i);

        while (hashElems[hashId] != nil) {
            collisionsAmount++; // added
            if (i + 1 == size) {
                doubleResize();
                i = -1;
            }
            i = (i + 1) % size;
            hashId = hashFunc(key, i);
        }

        hashElems[hashId] = newElem;
        nElems++;
    }
```

The resizeIfNeeded() doubles the size of the array if it's full and then proceeds to hash all the elements onto the new indexes.

Now as you can probably deduce from the put function above, each time there's a collision the hashFunc(key,i) method is called. It is also used when the array resizes to put the elements into the new memory however those calls won't be counted in the test.

hashFunc implementation :

```
@Override
    int hashFunc(int key, int i) {
        int m = getSize();

        key = key & Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        int hash = (key % m + i) % m;

        return hash;
    }
```

I've run some tests using the Profiler in NetBeans and exported the data to excel. I then realized that for many values of the memory that's initially reserved (Size column) the number of collisions for the MIT data is in MILLIONS whereas for the random integers as strings its always less than 300k. (Values in red concern me)

[image]

### **What is the reason for such a HUGE number of collisions when hashing the MIT data compared to the randomIntegersAsString data?**

*My attempt at finding an answer :*

After some further investigation I came to the conclusion this could be caused by the uneven distribution of text in the MIT data, since english is not perfect and some letters occur more frequently than others.

[image]

Whereas in the other test the data is much more evenly distributed.

[image]

I realized that the MIT data might create a larger risk of primary clustering because of that however Java's hashCode() method for string objects (hashcode = s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1] correct me if I'm wrong??) seems to not let collisions happen this easily and in such big quantities for this amount of data.

I feel stuck and don't know where to look for reasoning.

Comment: Hash function is important in this case that you need to override with more appropriate way to handle this kind of situation

Comment: Also you can change load factor if it is usable for you

Answer (score 1):

The probable reason for the difference in the two cases is due to the less than excellent quality of the Java string hash function.
If we analyze the distribution (diffusion) of the values of the hashes produced, we notice that in the case of strings originating from random numbers there is an absence of patterns, while in the case of hashes of the words in the file we notice the presence of patterns.

Graphical hashing analysis of 100000 causal numbers using String.hashCode():

[image: Graphical hashing analysis of 100000 causal numbers using String.hashCode()]

Graphical hashing analysis of 100000 words file using String.hashCode():

[image: Graphical hashing analysis of 100000 words file using String.hashCode()]

In the second case, you can see very well that the distribution is not uniform and there are numerous vertical "lines".

The solution is to use a hash function with better characteristics than that of java which always guarantees uniform distribution and absence of patterns. I suggest using [mzHash32()](https://github.com/matteo65/mzHash32) which is simple, fast, with minimal number of collisions and guarantees optimal distribution of hash values

```
public static int mzHash32(final byte[] data, int start, int length, int seed) {
    int hash = 0x95DE1432 ^ seed;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        hash = (0xA8657C5B * (i + data[start + i])) ^ (hash << 2) ^ (hash >>> 2);
    return hash;
}

public static int mzHash32(String str) {
    byte[] data = str.getBytes();
    return mzHash32(data, 0, data.length, 0);
}
```

Graphical hashing analysis of 100000 causal numbers using mzHash32():

[image: Graphical hashing analysis of 100000 causal numbers using mzHash32()]

Graphical hashing analysis of 100000 words file using mzHash32():

[image: Graphical hashing analysis of 100000 words file using mzHash32()]

Note the uniform distribution in both cases